# F# 4.0 code runs in interactive but doesn't compile in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I installed the following:

- Visual Studio 2015 (including F# 4.0 / listed under installed in Extensions and Updates tab)
- F# 4.0 (also set in PATH)

The following line won't compile in my Visual Studio:

```
List.contains 1 [1;2]

>> error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'contains' is not defined
```

But is running fine in the FSI run on Powershell, aswell as the FSI in Visual Studio. Powershell FSI and VS FSI also show the same F# Interactive version number.

Any ideas why it runs in interactive, but doesn't compile?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: I included the error message in the question

Comment: What version of FSharp.Core.dll does your project reference?

Comment: It was 4.3.1, changing the target runtime like @marklam suggested fixed the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the project properties page, on the first tab the "Target F# Runtime" should be set to 4.4.0.0.

If it is already, check that a NuGet package you've used hasn't added a reference to FSharp.Core 3.something - if it has, the NuGet updates tab should offer version 4, so update to that version.

Also check that the App.config isn't remapping FSharp.Core to the 4.3 version otherwise you'll get a strange runtime error about missing methods.